# How to implement dynamic Api routes in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is maybe set up 3 or more environments i.e qa, alpha, live. I'm using angular-cli but it currently supports development environment and production environment. So my question is, is there a way to dynamically add an apiUrl in production to check which one it should be using? I tried using an if statement to check the `window.location` and export the correct `const` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So basically there's a file that angular-cli generates for environment

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  config: {
    apiUrl: 'https://alpha.api.samplesite.com/v12/',
    serverUrl: 'https://alpha.api.samplesite.com/',
    assetUrl: ''
  }
};

I want the apiUrl be updated based on on the `window.location.hostname`